# 'com.company.Advertizing' is not an enclossing class

Tags: java, файлы, наследование

у меня есть два файла Advertizing.java и Main.java.
в первой файле - классы, которые я хочу вызвать в главном втором файле

фрагмент первого файла
Мне надо, чтобы код заработал в главном файле.
package com.company;

```
public class Advertizing {
    abstract class newspaper_advertising {
        private String customer;
        private String category;
        private String customortype;
        private String newspaper;
        private String position;

        public String getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public String getCustomer() {
            return customer;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        public String getCustomortype() {
            return customortype;
        }

        public String getNewspaper() {
            return newspaper;
        }


        public abstract double FullPayment();

        public abstract double Discount();

        public abstract double CostForPosition();

        newspaper_advertising(String customer, String customortype, String newspaper, String category, String position) {
            this.customer = customer;
            this.customortype = customortype;
            this.newspaper = newspaper;
            this.category = category;
            this.position = position;

        }
    }

    class PhotoAdvertising extends newspaper_advertising {...}

    class StringAdvertizing extends newspaper_advertising {...}
```

фрагмент второго файла

```
public class Main extends Advertizing{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    PhotoAdvertising ad = new PhotoAdvertising(40,"Julia","Person","Travel","Travel","middle");
    System.out.println(ad.FullPayment());
    StringAdvertizing ad1 = new StringAdvertizing(100,"Johnatan D.","Company", "Vogue","Fashion","bottom");
    System.out.println(ad1.FullPayment());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно объявить ваши внутренние классы как статические.

```
static abstract class newspaper_advertising {...}
static class PhotoAdvertising extends newspaper_advertising {...}
static class StringAdvertizing extends newspaper_advertising {...}
```